# Add variable in calling method

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to call a method which includes a variable of mine.

What I am trying:

```
var coin = "USDT";
var price = await api.GetPriceAsync(Symbol.BTC_+coin);
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: what we don't know is `Symbol.BTC` , `api.GetPriceAsync` and the ERROR YOU ARE GETTING

Comment: @zackraiyan var price = await api.GetPriceAsync(Symbol.BTC_USDT); is the regular method. I am trying to replace the USDT part by a variable called coin.

Comment: let me explain: Firstly we don't know what `api` method/function is , we don't know what `Symbol.BTC_` means as well neither do we know the namespaces they use :( And we don't know the issue you are facing .. Are you following [this](https://github.com/misha-bilous/HitBtcApi) ?

Comment: `I am trying to replace the USDT part by a variable called coin.` , USTD is a string here which is declared as `coin` , so u want `var coin = coin` ?

Comment: @zackraiyan sorry for being vague :( I am using this https://github.com/sonvister/Binance . The method I am using is: await api.GetPriceAsync(Symbol.BTC_USDT); I am interested in the Symbol.BTC_USDT part. Symbol. has many options and BTC_USDT is one of them. I want to use the string from the variable in this way: Symbol.BTC_+coin, from the variable coin.

Comment: GetPriceAsync want a STOCK Symbol as a string.  Should be : api.GetPriceAsync( "BTC-USD").  See : yahoo : https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to get the value of a static field named `Symbol.BTC_xxx` (e.g. [`BTC_USDT`](https://github.com/sonvister/Binance/blob/b6d26bb7c399c2c3974c2e7fcc0748f9488c44be/src/Binance/Symbol.cs#L308)), where `xxx` is your variable value. You'll need to use reflection for this:

```
var coin = "USDT";
var field = typeof(Symbol).GetField("BTC_" + coin, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var symbol = field.GetValue(null);
var price = await api.GetPriceAsync(symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment you use [github.com/sonvister/Binance](http://%20github.com/sonvister/Binance).

Looking at the class `Symbol`, we can find :

```
 public static readonly Symbol BTC_USDT = new Symbol(SymbolStatus.Trading, Asset.BTC, Asset.USDT, (0.00000100m, 10000000.00000000m, 0.00000100m), (0.01000000m, 10000000.00000000m, 0.01000000m), 10.00000000m, true, new List<OrderType> {OrderType.Limit,OrderType.LimitMaker,OrderType.Market,OrderType.StopLossLimit,OrderType.TakeProfitLimit});
```

Symbol is an object with many fields, it is not just a string you can split or truncate and add another bits. And even then you wouldn't find any other static method with name starting with "BTC_"

Answer (score 0):

Symbol has an conversion from string defined which should work if you remove the underscore from your input string.

```
Symbol symbol = (Symbol)"BTCUSDT";
var price = await api.GetPriceAsync(symbol);
```

Alternativly you should be able to access

```
Symbol.Cache
```

to get the cached symbols and then look up the one you need.